# How to return an object on the heap in c++?

Tags: c++, return, heap-memory

Currently I have two plans, either return the object itself,

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > myfunc()

    // initialize a 2d vector (matrix) with fixed size
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > *res = new std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > (nc, std::vector<std::string>(nr));

    // fill res up with some operations

    return *res;
}


int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > x = myfunc()
    // do something with x
    return 0;
}
```

or return a pointer:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >* myfunc()

    // initialize a 2d vector (matrix) with fixed size
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > *res = new std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > (nc, std::vector<std::string>(nr));

    // fill res up with some operations

    return res;
}


int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >* x = myfunc()
    // do something with x
    return 0;
}
```

But my gut feelings tell something is wrong with both of them. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any particular reason you need to use `new`? Why not just create an object normally, and return it by value?

Answer (score 2):

The first case is bad. You have a memory leak.

The second case is better. You have the option of deallocating the memory. Still better will be use of a smart pointer: `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`.

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>> myfunc()
{    
    // initialize a 2d vector (matrix) with fixed size
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > *res = new std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > (nc, std::vector<std::string>(nr));

    // fill res up with some operations

    return std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>>(res);
}
```

or

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>> myfunc()
{
    // initialize a 2d vector (matrix) with fixed size
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > *res = new std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > (nc, std::vector<std::string>(nr));

    // fill res up with some operations

    return std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>>(res);
}
```

Comment: @qed, yes. Checkout example code at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr.

Comment: But how come I got this error: no viable conversion from 'std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > *' to 'std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > >'

Comment: @qed, my bad. The return statement has to be changed to construct a `unique_ptr` explicitly. See the updated answer.

Comment: Nice, thanks. This means I don't have to worry about freeing up memory right?

Answer (score 0):

If the vector needs to be on the heap - use shared_ptrs, alternatively, avoid the ptrs all together; constructor the vector in main, and pass it into the function by reference.

CHeck out [C++ return value optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454068/c-return-value-optimization).