# Returning move-only type compiles even though copy-constructor is unavailable

Tags: c++, c++14

The following compiles without error:

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<int> f() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> x(new int(42));
    return x;
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> y = f();
}
```

I thought that the return value of `f()` was copy-initialized by `x`, but `std::unique_ptr` is a move-only type.  How is it that this isn't ill-formed because the copy constructor isn't available?  What is the relevant clause in the standard?  Is there somewhere that says if `f()` is a move-only type than a return statement becomes a move construction instead of a copy construction?

Comment: Not sure if it's a duplicate [C++ return value optimization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454068/c-return-value-optimization).

Comment: @iammilind: It's not.

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions

Comment: @vsoftco: That's more like it, though given that it asks about a different standard I'd be inclined to handle this by adding to the bottom of the question ("This was asked before for C++11: <your link>")

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I thought that the return value of `f()` was copy-initialized by `x`, but `std::unique_ptr` is a move-only type

The return value of `f()` is indeed copy-initialized from the expression `x`, but copy-initialization does not always imply copy-*construction*. If the expression is an rvalue, then the move constructor will be picked by overload resolution (assuming a move constructor is present).

Now although it is true that the expression `x` in the `return x;` statement is an lvalue (which may lead you to think that what I just wrote does not apply), in situations where a named object with automatic storage duration is returned, the compiler shall first try to treat the *id-expression* as an rvalue for overload resolution.

> What is the relevant clause in the standard? Is there somewhere that says if `f()` is a move-only type than a `return` statement becomes a move construction instead of a copy construction?

Per paragraph 12.8/32 of the C++ Standard ([class.copy]/32, draft N4296):

> When the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met, but not for an exception-declaration, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, or **when the expression in a `return` statement is a (possibly parenthesized) *id-expression* that names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body** or parameter-declaration-clause of the innermost enclosing function or lambda-expression, **overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue.** [...]

Comment: .. and therefore the move constructor is eligible, rendering _"the return value of f() was copy-initialized by x"_ false. `</completed-this-answer>`

Comment: Best to say _which_ C++ Standard you're quoting, since there have been several.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It does not make that statement false. AFAIK copy-initialization does not imply copy-construction. Concerning the Standard version, will edit that, thanks.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Oh ok well in that case the OP has a misconception (_"the return value of f() was copy-initialized by x, but std::unique_ptr is a move-only type. How is it that this isn't ill-formed because the copy constructor isn't available?"_) so the answer could still use a conclusion.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Agreed, will elaborate.

Comment: Yes, normally copy-initialization with an lvalue implies copy construction - but there is this special rule I was unaware of which says to treat it as an rvalue and move construct in this situation.