# Is this a bad way of initializing a vector?

Tags: c++

```
vector<vector<int>> levelOrder(TreeNode* root) {
    vector<vector<int>> result;
    queue<TreeNode *> que;

    if (root != nullptr) {
        que.emplace(root);
    }

    while (!que.empty()) {
        vector<int> level;
        int size = que.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            auto *front = que.front();
            que.pop();
            level.emplace_back(front->val);
            if (front->left != nullptr) {
                que.emplace(front->left);
            }
            if (front->right != nullptr) {
                que.emplace(front->right);
            }
        }
        result.emplace_back(move(level));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-level-order-traversal/description/

Above is the function that returns a vector>.

However, since I initialized the vector as a local variable `vector<vector<int>> result;` does it mean that it is a code smell for me to return it?

Since the vector is a local variable, it is allocated on the stack and the vector will get destroyed when this function call is over.

Should I have done this instead `auto results = new vector<vector<int>>`

Comment: You are returning a copy of the vector - perfectly OK.

Comment: I would not recommend the `new vector<vector<int>>` version. Returning by value is the best way imo.

Comment: I'd recommend the syntax `if (root != NULL) { ... }`.  Or, even better, `if (root != 0) { ... }`

Comment: @paulsm4 How would that be better than `!= nullptr`?

Comment: @paulsm4 Bah, `if (root)`, clearly. Or OP's version, but definitely not what you suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Since the software will not allow me to stop at that, I will elaborate. The "No" applies to the question only. I have not checked the code for errors. So, no, it is not wrong to return the result as written. There is no cost involved. Any modern compiler will use [return-value optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454068/c-return-value-optimization#19454278) to return the result.

It would be very bad form to use operator new. Doing so would put the burden of deleting the object upon the calling function. Search for "C++ RAII".

Comment: Why the down-vote? If this is wrong, please tell us why.

Comment: "Doing so would put the burden of deleting the object upon the calling function." - which is why we have smart pointers.

Comment: @Neil - True. But there is no reason to use a pointer here, smart, stupid, or of average IQ.